# Propane and septic pipes

Tags: safety, propane, septic

Is it safe to have a propane line (within a PVC conduit) cross a septic pipe (house to septic tank) underground?

Comment: Depends how well it's marked and/or remembered when there's a septic problem.

Comment: House to tank should be solid pipe compared to perforated pipe in bed.  So will not have to worry about sewer gas corroding gas pipe.